# How to alter parameter names in WebAPI 2 routing

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-web-api2

Using the default route

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I can reach an action implicit like GET http://ip:port/api/dogs/Henry:

```
public class DogsController:ApiController
{
    public Dog Get(string id) => DogRepository.GetDog(id);
}
```

But this, as far as I have been able to figure out, requires the action parameter name to match the routingdefinition: "id". I like descriptive parameter names, so how can I change the parameter name from "id" to "dogName"?

I know its obvious with one controller and one route, but I might have cats, goldfish and elephants in my api so "dogName" would not be a descriptive parametername in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `FromUriAttribute.Name` property for that:

```
public Dog Get([FromUri(Name = "id")]string dogName) => DogRepository.GetDog(dogName);
```

Note that in ASP.NET Core, the corresponding attribute is called `FromRoute` but behaves essentially the same (in this case).

Comment: Thx! FromRoute does not seem to exist in System.Web.Http though, but the FromUri attribute works as expected when used as per your example.  If you update I'll mark as answer ;)

Comment: Oh, it seems like `FromRoute` was introduced in `ASP.NET Core`. Will update, thanks!